# Visiting the UK after Tier 5 YM

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas

I am on a YMS from Canada for 2 years, that expires in April. I am planning to fly out to another country in Europe the day before it expires. I would like to travel around Europe for several weeks since I'm on this side of the pond, before flying home. However, given price of adding luggage to flights, as well as the inconvenience of carrying it, I was hoping to leave my bags in the UK for the 1.5 months that I travel, and return to the UK for 1 week at the end of May to grab my bags, and catch a flight at the beginning of June, one way, to Canada. The reason it's beginning June is that's when I found a flight that is under £350 one way and isn't 25 hours.

I have read many forums, with different experience from people. Basically, as I understand it, I'm legally entering as a visitor, but it's up the border agent to determine whether they believe I am actually coming as a visitor, or looking to continue my life here. 
If I bring with me a copy of my one way ticket to Canada, plus perhaps my resignation letters from my jobs in the UK, plus my flight and bus history around Europe from April to end of May - might that suffice?

Comment: Thanks, both! I suppose my fear is that I don't want to be flagged as untrustworthy or a risk, especially with the new points based sponsorship system I'm hoping that I might be able to come back next year with a sponsorship and at the very least, come for a visit in the next few months for a week or two to visit my British partner. He will be staying in Britain and I'll be returning to Canada and we're sort of 'testing' it out because we're not ready to get married yet. So I'd like to ensure that I can come visit in a few months' time despite having come back for a week to collect my bags and

Comment: I wonder too if using the eGate comes off as sneaky? Like, if it doesn't pull you up, does it look on your record the next time, like you're trying to avoid getting grilled as @kiradotee says

Answer (score 4):

As a Canadian citizen then you don't need a visa to enter the UK as a visitor.

As you are just entering for a period of 1 week, have no intention to stay longer, then this should not represent a problem for you so long that you are able to;

- Prove that you have onward travel arrangements out of the UK (printout of your
  flight confirmation)
- Have sufficient funds for your stay in the UK
- Have accommodation arranged (printout of hotel booking, or email from friend saying that you can stay there)

The border agents want to be sure that you will leave the UK.  So as long as you already have a flight booked (which is anyway normally cheaper when done well in advance), haven't previously overstayed in the UK, then they should be happy.

And if asked just be honest and say "I previously been in the UK on YMS scheme, I have been travelling around continental Europe for xx months, and I am visiting friends in the UK and collecting property that they kept for me before returning home to Canada to my family on xx date."

Comment: Would it be beneficial to try and use ePassport gates to potentially avoid speaking with the Border Officer? Still obviously following your advice in case the ePassport gate directs them for a manual check. I hope it's not considered as a red flag for doing so? 

Comment: @kiradotee generally if eligible the immigration service prefer people to use eGates.  As a short term visitor with a Canadian passport then this should be available to the OP and will not cause them any issues if they elect to use this method.  But this might not be supported in all location, especially if coming from Europe. (e.g.  I believe that when I went through Stansted in November the eGates were still only available to EEA citizens).